# Only the first 255 characters of the long text field was kept when create a query using a table in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a field with a long paragraph (long text type) in a table, once I conduct a query on it, the paragraph then being cut off in query's datasheet view (Only the first 255 characters was kept). Anybody know what caused the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean; could you add a screen shot to your question?

Comment: have you tried to increase the row size of datasheet view? by default you see only one line. by increasing the row size may be you will see your text clearly.

Comment: Yes, I've checked. it surely got cut off. Only the first 255 characters was kept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem with Memo or Long text (As they are now called) fields once they are queried in certain ways.

There is a full explanation here http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html

It is caused by limitations with Access, but the link shows a number of workarounds.